# Convert LDAP Date in firebird

Tags: sql, date, time, firebird

I am getting date in LDAP format (DB Firebird).
Now I want to convert

1. from LDAP date in format `2017-08-01 00:00:00`
2. from format `2017-08-01 00:00:00` to LDAP date in SQL

What is the PSQL Stored Functions to convert LDAP Date to date format `2017-08-01 00:00:00`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am getting date in LDAP" - this is absolutely impossible to understand. show the example of that data and the table definition (schema) where you have it. And, there is most probably no such function, you would have to write stored procedure for it.

Comment: What is a 'ldap date'? What format does it need to be? How do you store it in the database (as a `TIMESTAMP` or something else)?